# How to set the border style in one place and reference it throughout XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I would like to have one var/attribute that I set the border style and reference it so if i want to change the border from 1pt to 2pt I don't need to change it in various locations.

For example at the moment I do this;

```
<fo:table border="1pt solid black"  table-layout="fixed"
  width="100%" display-align="center">
 <fo:table-column column-width="10%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="10%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="23%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="8%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="11%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="8%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="20%" border-right="1pt solid black"/>
 <fo:table-header>...
```

I would prefer something like;

```
<xsl:variable
    name="border"
    select="1pt solid black">
</xsl:variable>

<fo:table border="$border"  table-layout="fixed"
  width="100%" display-align="center">
 <fo:table-column column-width="10%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="10%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="23%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="8%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="11%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="8%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-column column-width="20%" border-right="$border"/>
 <fo:table-header>...
```

So my question really is this possible and if so whats the correct syntax?

Any help would be great,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variable like so (using apostrophes, to indicate an literal string, not a xpath expression)

```
<xsl:variable name="border" select="'1pt solid black'" />
```

Then, use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to use it in an attribute

```
<fo:table-column column-width="20%" border-right="{$border}"/>
```

Alternatively, you could achieve this with [Attribute Sets](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-sets). Define an attribute set like so

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="border">
    <xsl:attribute name="border-right" select="'12pt solid black'" />
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Then use it as follows

```
<fo:table-column column-width="20%" xsl:use-attribute-sets="border"/>
```

With attribute sets, you could have multiple attributes in the set.

Comment: The other interesting aspects of attribute sets (which this question admittedly doesn't seem to require) are that multiple `xsl:attribute-set` with the same name are merged and that the `xsl:attribute` definitions are instantiated each time that they are used, meaning that the generated attributes can be different in different contexts if you wanted.